# ZedGraph PointEditEvent in only one curve

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I would like to use PointEditEvent in my cart.

But I have two curves in this cart, and only one can be edited.

I tried canceled event if check is wrong curve. But I can´t do it because it´s fires after operation is completed.

A delegate that receives notification after a point-edit operation is completed.

```
string ZedGraphControl_PointEditEvent(ZedGraphControl sender, GraphPane pane, CurveItem curve, int iPt) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it, you need to use MouseDownEvent and MouseUpEvent of ZedGraph control. In MouseDown event you should find which curve was clicked with FindNearestPoint and then if it is needed curve - enable horizontal and vertical edit. On MouseUp event you should disable edit.

For example:

```
    private bool zedGraphControl_MouseDownEvent(ZedGraphControl sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedPoint = new PointF(e.X, e.Y);
        var pane = zedGraphControl.MasterPane.FindPane(clickedPoint);
        if (pane == null) return false;
        int index;
        CurveItem outCurve;
        if (!pane.FindNearestPoint(new PointF(e.X, e.Y), out outCurve, out index)) return false;
        if (outCurve.Label.Text == "Needed curve")  //Here you check that user clicked on needed curve
        {
            zedGraphControl.IsEnableHEdit = true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool zedGraphControl_MouseUpEvent(ZedGraphControl sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        zedGraphControl.IsEnableHEdit = false;
        return false;
    }
```